# use ng-bind-html with URL

Tags: angularjs

Currently I have a div with `ng-bind-html` that I use to bind to HTML that I pass in

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(message.text)" />
```

Currently `message.text` is HTML. I would rather like to pass in a URL and have that HTML inserted in to the `div`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to retrieve the HTML from the webpage available at the `url` and insert it in the div?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would make a custom directive to do such a thing.

I would send the url as attribute paramater, make the directive fetch the html with $http.get(), and when its loaded, append it to the html.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the source as:

```
<div ng-bind-html="URl | safeHtml"></div>
```

And need to add `$sce` for safe binding of the url with this directive:

```
app.filter('safeHtml', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

**Edit:**

Rather than direct binding the url, embed it in iframe and use it for safe binding:

```
$scope.URL = <iframe ng-src="url"></iframe>
```

Comment: this is tried and tested, i have been using this to bind third party url to my application. why downvote?

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

```
<input ng-model="myUrl"/>
<div id="myDiv" />
```

And then add a watch for `myUrl`, and make a request for the url each time it changes:

```
$scope.$watch('message.text', function(newValue) {
    $.ajax({ url: 'newValue', success: function(data) { 
        $("#myDiv").html(data);
    }});
}
```